# Remove time in the notification message in android

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

[image]

Hi,

I tried to implement the notification message using GCM. I am using the following code to display the notification content.

```
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, DemoActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle(null)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(msg))
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

However as you can see, there is an empty space in the content title area and time at the right most part in first row.

Can you please let me know how time field can be removed?

Edit:
It is being shown at the top. And if I use setWhen(0) in the builder, it will remove the time but it still occupies an empty space in the first row.

Comment: Time can be removed but still it occupies the first empty row.

Comment: Use custom layout if needed.

Comment: You set a `null` content title of course the title area is going to be empty...its kind of a critical part of the notification structure on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Empty space is because you are setting title as null. Ideally, you should set title to Notification. If there is any special use-case where you need to have only one TextView, you can go for Custom Layouts for notification.

Refer: Custom Notification Layouts in  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html